# How to break a list into sublists whenever a specific list element is encountered?

Tags: python, list

I have this list :

```
main_list = [[1, 'N'], [2, 'N'], [3, 'Y'], [4, 'Y'], [5, 'N'], [6, 'N']]
```

My requirement is:
1. I need to loop through main_list and when `main_list[i][1]=='N'`, I need to keep on adding `main_list[i]` to `sub_list1`
2. But the moment I encounter `main_list[i][1]=='Y'`, two things should happen:
  - `main_list` element having `'Y'` should not get added to any `sub_list`
  - `sub_list1` should stop
3. When I encounter `main_list[i][1]=='N'` again, a new sub_list i.e `sub_list2` will get generated and list elements should get added to this new sub_list
4.  The final output should be like this:

```
sub_list1 = [[1, 'N'], [2, 'N']]
sub_list2 = [[5, 'N'], [6, 'N']]
```

could you please help with the approach?
Thanks in advance

Comment: This site is a repository of specific questions and answers, not a coding service.

Comment: Take a look at `itertools.groupby` document

Comment: Show your own efforts first.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
from itertools import groupby
main_list = [[1, 'N'], [2, 'N'], [3, 'Y'], [4, 'Y'], [5, 'N'], [6, 'N']]

i = 0
d = {}
for key, group in groupby(main_list, lambda x: x[1]):    
    if key == 'Y' : continue 
    d['sub_list{}'.format(i+1)] = []       
    for g in group:        
        d['sub_list{}'.format(i+1)].append(g)

    i += 1
```